# simplexml php get xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

If I have a document like this:

```
<!-- in doc.xml -->
<a>
  <b>
    greetings?
    <c>hello</c>
    <d>goodbye</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

Is there any way to use simplexml (or any php builtin really) to get a string containing:

```
greetings?
<c>hello</c>
<d>goodbye</d>
```

Whitespace and such doesn't matter.

Thanks!

Comment: I hope you mean `<d>goodbye</d>` instead `<d>goodbye</c>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must admit this wasn't as simple as one would think. This is what I came up with:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('doc.xml');

// find just the <b> node(s)
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$results = $xpath->query('/a/b');

// get entire <b> node as text
$node = $results->item(0);
$text = $xml->saveXML($node);

// remove encapsulating <b></b> tags
$text = preg_replace('#^<b>#', '', $text);
$text = preg_replace('#</b>$#', '', $text);

echo $text;
```

#### Regarding the XPath query

The query returns all matching nodes, so if there are multiple matching `<b>` tags, you can loop through `$results` to get them all.

My query for `'/a/b'` assumes that `<a>` is the root and `<b>` is its child/immediate descendant. You could alter it for different scenarios. Here's [an XPath reference](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp). Some adjustments might include:

- `'a/b'` –– `<b>` is child of `<a>`, but `<a>` is anywhere, not just in the root
- `'a//b'` –– `<b>` is a descendant of `<a>` no matter how deep, not just a direct child
- `'//b'` –– all `<b>` nodes anywhere in the document

#### Regarding method of obtaining string contents

I tried using `$node->nodeValue` or `$node->textContent`, but both of them strip out the `<c>` and `<d>` tags, leaving just the text contents of those. I also tried casting it as a DOMText object, but that didn't directly work and was more trouble than it was worth.

#### Regarding the use of regular expressions

It could be done without regex, but I found it easiest to use them. I wanted to make sure that I only stripped the `<b>` and `</b>` at the very beginning and end of the string, just in case there were other `<b>` nodes within the contents.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Since you already know the XML format:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('doc.xml'); 
$str = $xml->b;
$str .= "<c>".$xml->b->c."</c>";
$str .= "<d>".$xml->b->d."</d>";

echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, good point. That's a little shorter, as long as the format is guaranteed to always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using DOM (to balance the SimpleXML answers!) that outputs the contents of all of the first `<b>` element.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('doc.xml');
$bee = $doc->getElementsByTagName('b')->item(0);

$innerxml = '';
foreach ($bee->childNodes as $node) {
    $innerxml .= $doc->saveXML($node);
}
echo $innerxml;
```